# Determine if a python fraction can have an equivalent decimal

Tags: python, math, sympy

I need to write a python function that takes, as an argument, an object of class "Fraction", and determines whether the fraction can be represented in decimal format. For example, 1/2 can be represented by 0.5, but 1/3 has no decimal equivalent with finite number of digits (0.333333333 is an approximated value).

My approach was to compare the fraction with the numerator divided by the denominator as follows (assume that "frac" is the Fraction object):

```
 if frac == frac.numerator / frac.denominator:
      print('has decimal representaion')
 else:
      print('has no decimal representation')
```

but this doesn't work in many cases. For example Python mistakes the comparison `Fraction(347, 1000) == 0.347`, it returns `False` although it should be `True`.
I know that python has a problem related to floating point operations, therefor I am looking for a workaround or a package that solves this problem.

Note: I used sympy but in sympy the comparison `S(1)/3 == 1/3` returns `True`, where I need it to be `False`.

Comment: If the fraction is in its lowest terms, then it has an exact decimal representation if the denominator has no prime factors other than 2 and 5.

Comment: I know but this means that I will use loops to find out the prime factors, which will take too long time in case of large primes.

Answer (score 11):

Using this:

> If the denominator is has any prime factors other than 2 and 5, it doesn't have an exact decimal representation. – khelwood

You could test this by dividing out the 2s and then 5s and then checking if the result is 1:

```
def has_decimal_representaion(frac):
    d = frac.denominator
    for n in (2, 5):
        while d % n == 0:
            d = d / n
    return d == 1
```

Comment: I amended that comment to include "if the fraction is in its lowest terms"

Comment: I thought that Fraction objects were self reducing.

Comment: Aha. Then my qualifier is redundant. Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with checking `Fraction(1, 3) == float(1/3)` is that `float(1/3)` is also technically a rational number, since it's a finitely represented floating point number. To be sure that rational number is `6004799503160661/18014398509481984`:

```
>>> (1/3).as_integer_ratio()
(6004799503160661, 18014398509481984)
```

This method would only work if computers could store infinitely many digits for a floating point number, which is impossible.

As for the easier test suggested by khelwood, if the denominator has factors other than 2 or 5, you can use SymPy's `factorint` with the `limit` argument to prevent it from trying to find large prime factors. Note that `fraction.Fraction` and `sympy.Rational` objects are always reduced to lowest terms automatically, so you don't need to worry about that.

```
def is_representable(rational):
    d = sympy.Rational(rational).q
    return not bool(set(sympy.factorint(d, limit=10).keys()) - {2, 5})
```